# AWS CLI file extension association warning on Windows

Tags: windows, aws-cli

Using aws cli with python 3 on Windows, always getting a warning, but the program runs well after this message.

For example:

```
>>> aws --version --debug
Не найдено сопоставление для расширения имени файла .py.
aws-cli/1.15.83 Python/3.6.0 Windows/7 botocore/1.10.82
```

(vaguely -' Cannot find association for filename extension .py')

Any idea which part of aws scripts issues this warning and how to fix it? At what part does aws use Windows call?

Answer (score 3):

As @Evgeny describes in Windows after install AWS CLI the file `aws.cmd` has this line that calls the command `assoc` and produces the warning:

```
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('assoc .py') do (
```

The command `assoc .py` shows if there is an association to python files in Windows. If you don't have a python executable associated with *.py files in your main command line (no in environments of Anaconda).

You can test that opening a command line window and try to run a simple script in a folder this way:

```
    >test.py
```

If you get an error and you like to remove the warning you have to make a new association for python files, with one of this options.

- By command line (as administrator)

```
    assoc .py=py_auto_file
    ftype py_auto_file="C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

- By GUI changing Defaults apps

Right clic any file with extension *.py and select properties, and select a program that manage this file, for example in "C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" or change the default app.

In Windows 10 you can follow this sequence "Start  menu, select Settings  > Apps > Default apps"

Answer (score 0):

you have to meet the dependency with: https://www.python.org/downloads/

so that windows could have something to register file-type `.py` with.

or you'd have to register `.py` to open with `python3.exe` (or alike).

Comment: Can you point out where Windows attempts to resolve the dependency?

Comment: `Не найдено сопоставление для расширения имени файла .py.` ...this means, that file-type `.py` has no registered handler - while it should only be logical to install Python 3, so that there will be a registered handler.

Comment: Also I do have python installed obviously, not sure going to python download page is much help. Just in case it was not clear in my question - the aws commands do execute, but issue the warning.

Comment: this is the message - what invokes the message do you know? I'm not calling any python scripts, ```Scripts/aws``` excutes fine.

Comment: @EPo then you have to register `.py` to open with `python3.exe` (or alike)... because this is required, so that one can double-click onto `.py` and it would execute. this would at least mute that warning.

Comment: Still unclear from your answer what makes Windows call the .py script.

Comment: because of https://pypi.org/project/awscli ...and it also could be, that you currently have python2 registered as handler (they're similar, but not really compatible). see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html

Comment: the docs refer to ` %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts` (demanding Python 3.6), while it is not clear from where you may run that `aws` command... https://wilsonmar.github.io/aws-onboarding/ hints for, that this may be related to `boto`.

Comment: `pip install awscli` installs `aws` script in your `<python installation>\Scripts` directory, which is visible because it is in `PATH` variable

Comment: `boto` is a python dependecy, unlikely it need Windows call to execute. I think the warning is issued by 'aws' script on initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get feedback on a [issue on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3518). Basically, there is a one line change that can supress the warning.

In `aws.cmd` instead of:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('assoc .py') do (
```

use:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('assoc .py 2^> nul') do (
```

This diverts warnings to null. There is also a 
[pull request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/2005/commits/abf743bf3649702e26ac103ccc8b39d9a27abe43)
with this suggested change, but it was not mergerged to code unfortunately.

Anyone experiencing this problem can change a local file `aws.cmd` as `<your python directory>/Scripts` folder.